# Is it possible to install Tails OS on a hard disk drive and how?

Tags: tails

I have an old laptop to spare and would like to know if it is possible to install [Tails OS](https://tails.boum.org/index.en.html) on a hard disk drive and how?

I know it is meant to be a live system but I would like to have something little faster. Faster booting, faster starting programs, etc. It is all quite slow from the USB stick, although I already have persistence on the USB.

Comment: Based on the documentation by the project.  It does not appear that its possible to install this operating system onto a HDD.